# Botón sobre imágenes en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, web, vscode

Estoy realizando una página con css y HTML y tengo dos imágenes y quiero colocar un botón en el centro de las dos imágenes. Algo así quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo de código es esto (HTML):

```
<div class="Caja1inicio"><h1 class="intro" align="center">¿Necesitas ayuda con un contador o estudio contable?</h1>
    <img style="float:right"class="imgintro"src="Imágenes/curso-37.jpg" alt="Estudio Contable Córdoba" height="400" width="750">
    <img style="float:left"src="Imágenes/contaduria-1-2.jpg" alt="Estudio Contable Córdoba" height="400" width="600">
    <!--<a class="btncontacto" href="Contacto.html">Contactanos</a>-->
</div>
```

Y  estuve probando e investigando para hacerlo con CSS y decía que tenía que poner el botón con `position:relative` y con `position:absolute`, pero no puedo dar con la tecla...

Espero que me puedan ayudar...

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando dimensiones estáticas podrías usar `position: absolute` y situar el botón según más te convenga.

En este caso ya que tu imagen izquierda mide 600px de ancho, la derecha 750px y de altura ambas tienen 400px, puedes probar con estos estilos:

```
<a class="btncontacto" href="Contacto.html"
    style="position: absolute; left: calc(600px/2 - 40px); top: calc(400px/2 - 10px);">
    Contactanos
</a>
```

Sobre la propiedad de **position** en CSS puedes consultar [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Por otro lado te recomendaría que leas sobre ***diseño responsive*** para que tu sitio web sea adaptable a cualquier resolución. Sobre esto te dejo dos lecturas por aquí:

- https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/
- https://desarrolloweb.com/manuales/responsive-web-design.html

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo que te puede servir.. yo te recomendaría que editaras la imagen y las unieras, porque cada img se muestra como un bloque y eso te puede traer problemas.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px:
}
.row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.col-12 {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
       }
.hero__background {
    padding: 0 80px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.875rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-primary {
    background: #65d097;
    border-color: #65d097;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
        <title>Plantilla de pagina</title>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="hero__background" style="background-image: url(./img/sample002.png);">
                <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 60px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 30px;">¿Necesitas ayuda con un contador o estudio contable?</h1>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary">
                                <span>contactanos</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por el aporte. Lo tendré en cuenta. Saludos!